# python code to generate a Nigerian plate number

Tags: python-3.x

I need a code designed with python to generate vehicle plate numbers

```
for platecode in range(100):
    print('KJA'+'platecode'+'AA')
```

expected result is = `KJA001AA` till `100`

Comment: And what is wrong with your code so far?

Comment: how about you use the actual `platecode` variable instead of a string? You also need to zero pad it

Comment: when run platecode type out plate code instead of rangeing 0 to 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're not using the platecode variable, you're just putting it in as a string. 'platecode' (string) =/= platecode (variable). And as a comment stated, you want to zero-pad it. To do so use the format method:

```
for platecode in range(100):
    print("KJA{0:03d}AA".format(platecode))
```

(Note that we use the `platecode` variable, not a string `'platecode'`.)

To explain what the `format` method is doing: When `format` is called, it replaces braced sections (`"{0:03d}"`) with the arguments to `format` (in this case, `platecode`). The first 0 says to access the argument at index 0; the colon indicates the beginning of the [format specifier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). The second zero says to zero-pad the number; the 3 says to use a minimum of 3 digits; and the d indicates to print in base 10, decimal.

Comment: @AdekoyejoAdeloye: If you think this answer is helpful, remember mark this answer as accepted. Please see: [How does accepting an answer work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234)